# Regex to match strings containing two of any character but not three

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want a Regex to match strings containing the same character twice (not necessarily consecutive) but not if that character appears three times or more.

For example, given these two inputs:

```
abcbde
abcbdb
```

The first, `abcbde` would match because it contains `b` twice. However, `abcbdb` contains `b` three times, so that would not match.

I have created this Regex, however it matches both:

```
(\w).*\1{1}
```

I've also tried to use the `?` modifier, however that still matches `abcbdb`, which I don't want it to.

Comment: This looks tricky. You don't know in advance which character should appear exactly twice, right? In that case, what about `ababa`? It should match because of `b` but should also not match because of `a` - which is it? In either case, you'd need a regex engine that can handle lookbehind for groups that have not yet matched; not many can do that. So we need to know which engine you're using. But I guess it will be much easier and cleaner to sort the string and then check that for consecutive runs of identical characters - that would be easy to do with a regex or programmatically.

Comment: Please  tag a regex flavor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two checks: a first check to ensure no character exists 3 times in the input, and a second check to look for one that exists 2 times:

```
^(?!.*(\w).*\1.*\1).*?(\w).*\2
```

This is horribly inefficient compared to, say, using your programming language to construct an array of character frequencies, requiring only 1 pass through the entire input. But it works.

Comment: I may have been overthinking this :) Great solution!

Comment: Thanks Tim :P Happens to the best of us!

Comment: This does not match `'xxyyy'`. The questions asks if the string contains a character exactly twice (`'x'` in my example) with no further condition.